# How to respond with array of query results in Node/ Express/ Postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

newbie here. I am trying to fetch an array of objects from my local database through two `select` queries, using knex.js and postgresql like so:

```
app.get('/trips/:name', (req, res) => {
  const {name} = req.params;
  db.select('tripid').from('member')
    .where('name', '=', name)
    .then(data => {
      const array = data.map(elem => {
        db.select('tripname')
          .from('trip')
          .where('id', '=', elem.tripid)
          .then(obj => {
            array.push(obj[0])
          })
    })
    return array
  })
  .then(arr => res.json(arr))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err))
})
```

I want to push all the objects that the second query returns into an array and respond to the front end. However, it always returns an empty array, which I suspect because 
`.map`
is asynchronous, so the array is returned before the loop finishes. How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks. Sorry if my code is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this way using async await :

```
app.get('/trips/:name', async (req, res) => {
  try{
  const {name} = req.params;
   let arr = await db.select('tripid').from('member').where('name', '=', name);
   if(arr && arr.length>0){
     for(let item of arr){
          let tripResult  = await db.select('tripname').from('trip').where('id', '=', item.tripid).catch(e=>e);
          item.trip = tripResult && tripResult[0]? tripResult[0]:null;
     }
   }
   return res.json(arr);
  }catch(error){
    return res.status(400).json(error);
  }
}
```

2nd way :

```
app.get('/trips/:name',(req, res) => {

  const {name} = req.params;
   db.select('tripid').from('member').where('name', '=', name)
   .then(arr =>{   


     Promise.all(arr.map(item =>{

     db.select('tripname')
       .from('trip')
       .where('id', '=', item.tripid)
       .then((tripResult=>{
            item.trip = tripResult && tripResult[0]? tripResult[0]:null;
            return item;
       }).catch(e=>e);

    })
   ).then(arr => {
        return res.status(200).json(arr);
   })   

}).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
```

Comment: The first way works great, but the second way is still returning empty arrays. But thank you!

Comment: @Gaplachem , i have updated 2nd way, can you please try and check it is working or not ?

Comment: The 2nd way is now returning an array of null objects

Comment: @Gaplachem , ok i will update my answer soon and let you know